# How to Update (pass) multiple data from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC 5 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I got a problem with passing data from view to controller. Actually, I tried to search and learn from many question and answer in this community but it still not work. It's always sent 'null' back in controller.

For now I have no idea how to solve it.

The concept of this view is for , show the employee with Evaluator and Appraisal form. The evaluator and the form type can change. This view is for view and update if Evaluator or form need to change.

So here is the code:

Model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;

namespace OTWebApplication.Models
{
    public class AP_UserForm
    {
        [Key()]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public String UFID { get; set; }
        public String UF_YID { get; set; }
        public String UF_FormID { get; set;}
        public String UF_FormName { get; set; }
        public String UF_EvaID { get; set; } 
        public String UF_EvaName { get; set; }
        public String UF_RootID { get; set; } 
        public String UF_RootName { get; set; }
        public String UF_Available { get; set; } 
        public String UF_STID { get; set; } 
    }

    public class AP_UserFormL
    {
        public List<AP_UserForm> AP_UserForm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
@model OTWebApplication.Models.AP_UserFormL
<form asp-action="UpdateAll" method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>EmployeeID</th>
                    <th>EmployeeName</th>
                    <th>EvaluatorID</th>
                    <th>FormName</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AP_UserForm.Count(); i++)
                {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForm[i].UFID" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForm[i].UF_RootName" class="form-control" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForm[i].UF_EvaID" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ARoot)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.ARoot_ID">@item.ARoot_Name</option>
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForm[i].UF_FormID" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Form)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.FormID">@item.FormName</option>
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select asp-for="@Model.AP_UserForm[i].UF_Available" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="0">ไม่ต้องประเมิน</option>
                                        <option value="1">ประเมินปกติ</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <button input type="submit" value="Edit">Update</button>
</Form>
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateAll(AP_UserFormL model)
{
    ModelState.Clear();

    if (model != null && model.AP_UserForm.Count>0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not null");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("null"); 
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ManageAP", "Appraisal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Network tab (payload, preview section) to verify if front-end is sending the data as you expect (the correct format that is to be received by controller).

If it is sending the data correctly, then try adding [FromBody] tag in action method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateAll([FromBody] AP_UserFormL model)
```

Comment: Checked in payload, and all the data was correct.
added [FromBody] already.

Still sent NULL back to controller.